# R: Monthly bins based on source date ranges

Tags: r, date

Binning examples for R I've found seem to assume the source data has a single date (or date/time). I've discrete start and stop dates for user accounts ranging over years 2002-2017. I want to output counts of the number of accounts active, using monthly bins, during the overall range 2002-17.

The data is currently in dd/mm/yyyy strings,though I could easily change that format if needed; rows are sorted by ascending start date. for example

```
Start       Stop
04/09/2006  23/01/2014
...
06/07/2008  11/03/2017
...
30/09/2010  22/04/2016
```

The resulting counts would be, for example:

```
Mar 2006    0
Jan 2007    1
Mar 2011    3
Jun 2015    2
Sep 2016    1
...etc.
```

The aim of generating the counts is to the plot the total active accounts over time. I'm open to getting daily counts and then aggregating by month if easier. I'm stuck at the start though: bin where the source is a date range and not a single date.

Comment: So what do you want to do now ? Did you try something ?

Comment: Um, something like the accepted solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the columns to `"yearmon"` class and use `mapply` to generate the year/months `ym` covered. Then count how many of each year/month occur and merge that with a data frame having all the year/months between Jan 2002 and Dec 2017 giving `M_na` and replace NAs with 0 giving `M`.

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- transform(DF, Start = as.yearmon(Start), Stop = as.yearmon(Stop))

ym <- unlist(mapply(seq, DF2$Start, DF2$Stop, MoreArgs = list(by = 1/12)))
Ag <- aggregate(ym^0, list(ym = as.yearmon(ym)), sum)

M_na <- merge(Ag, data.frame(ym = as.yearmon(seq(2002, 2017+11/12, 1/12))), all.y = TRUE)
M <- transform(M_na, x = replace(x, is.na(x), 0))


plot(x ~ ym, M, type = "h", xlab = "", ylab = "Count", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, 2002:2017)
```

(continued after image)

[image: screenshot]

**magrittr**

This could also be expressed as a magrittr pipeline like this:

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

M <- DF %>%
   transform(Start = as.yearmon(Start), Stop = as.yearmon(Stop)) %$%
   unlist(mapply(seq, Start, Stop, MoreArgs = list(by = 1/12))) %>%
   { aggregate(.^0, list(ym = as.yearmon(.)), sum) } %>%
   merge(data.frame(ym = as.yearmon(seq(2002, 2017+11/12, 1/12))), all.y = TRUE) %>%
   transform(x = replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
```

**Note:** We assume the following input with Date class columns:

```
Lines <- "
Start       Stop
04/09/2006  23/01/2014
06/07/2008  11/03/2017
30/09/2010  22/04/2016"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
DF <- transform(DF, Start = as.Date(Start, fmt), Stop = as.Date(Stop, fmt))
```

Comment: Thanks again. BTW, using your original solution, all works except for one apparent glitch. The count values for bins Jul-17 through Dec-17 should all be zero but each has a value. By comparison, Jan-02 to Nov-02 have a zero count as expected.  I'd assumed the former were mistakes in my data but the latest date in any record is 30/6/17. Odd. Even so, really pleased to have got this far.

Comment: tail(M) shows that Jul-17 to Dec-17 are zero contrary to your comment.  Suggest you start a fresh R session, paste into R the code to in the Note at the end of the answer and then paste in the code in the body of the answer and then run tail(M).

Comment: Thank you. A fresh session seemed to clear that error.  (User error, I forgot to reloading data using the corrected version - the late 2017 false counts were actual errors in my original data set.). Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your dates as month-year and then apply a factor with all the month-years values you should get what you want

```
# creating data for example
dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('01/01/2002', format='%m/%d/%Y'), 
                    as.Date('12/31/2017', format='%m/%d/%Y'), 
                    by="day"), 30)

# use the cut function to round up to the first of each month if you like
months <- format(as.Date(cut(dates, breaks= 'month')), '%b %Y')
# cut function is not necessary if you prefer to skip to the format
months <- format(dates, '%b %Y')

# Created an ordered vector of months and years
ord_months <- c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
ord_year <- as.character(2002:2017)
# create an ordered vector of month years
months_ordered <- apply(expand.grid(ord_months, ord_year), 1, paste, collapse = ' ')
head(months_ordered)

# factor the format and apply the factored vector as the levels
monthsF <- factor(months, levels=months_ordered)
table(monthsF)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've gone with the approach above (as I need the day component elsewhere) but your suggestion is a useful alternate.